# Angular client cannot access Localhost in Google Compute Engine

Tags: angular, google-compute-engine

I have an Angular client and a C++ server that communicate using WebSockets on localhost.  This works fine on my PC.

I was planning to host my Angular app using Google Compute Engine, and have my C++ server located on the same VM as my client, and have the client and server communicate using localhost. However, when I deploy the client, the client returns the following error when the client WebSocket tries to connect to the c++ server that is listening on localhost port 8060:

```
failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Does anybody knows why my client app cannot access localhost on the Google Compute Engine VM? Am I missing some configuration that would allow this communication to occur?

Comment: What is reporting this error? More details are required.

Answer (score 0):

**First make sure that port 8060 is open in Windows firewall.**

To open up a port in a Windows [fallow these instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-a-windows-firewall-for-database-engine-access?view=sql-server-ver15) from official Microsoft documentation:

> To open a port in the Windows firewall for TCP access
> On the Start menu, click Run, type WF.msc, and then click OK.
>
> In the Windows Firewall with Advanced Security, in the left pane, right-click Inbound Rules, and then click New Rule in the action pane.
>
> In the Rule Type dialog box, select Port, and then click Next.
>
> In the Protocol and Ports dialog box, select TCP. Select Specific local ports, and then type the port number of the instance of the Database Engine, such as 1433 for the default instance. Click Next.
>
> In the Action dialog box, select Allow the connection, and then click Next.
>
> In the Profile dialog box, select any profiles that describe the computer connection environment when you want to connect to the Database Engine, and then click Next.
>
> In the Name dialog box, type a name and description for this rule, and then click Finish.

**Second - check if the GCP firewall doesn't block the connection**; to be absolutely sure you can [create a rule for that](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls#creating_firewall_rules). You can use either GCP's console or `gcloud` utility (very handy).